# PHP ksort seems unaffected by setlocale

Tags: php, sorting

I've been given an array that needs to be sorted by its key (associative array), and it may have some accented characters in it (à, è, ì, etc.). If it helps any, I do know the language that will be used, so I should be able to set a locale in theory. So, my original theory was to do it like so:

```
setlocale(LC_COLLATE, 'fre');
ksort($array, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
```

This doesn't appear to change the way ksort works at all - Accented characters are always last alphabetically when i'd think they should at least come after regular characters. For instance, 'èvery' would come after 'every', but not after 'fair'. So, then I started to look into collator but couldn't find a way to sort by the array keys. If anyone has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the language code right?

Comment: Works here, so indeed, most likely locale issue.

Comment: I'm not certain, I based 'fre' off of this: "Category/locale names can be found in » RFC 1766 and » ISO 639. Different systems have different naming schemes for locales." from http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php and I used the second ISO 639 code on the linked page (showed fra/fre)

Comment: Is this on a Windows or a Linux (or Mac) server? I believe the locale codes are slightly different on Windows... e.g. 'nl_NL' on Linux and 'nld_nld' on Windows.

Comment: It's a Linux install, guess I'll see what I can figure from that..

Comment: You should make that a suggested answer Mark, that was the issue. fr_FR makes it work!

Comment: @David - duly done, for the benefit of others that might fall fould of the same problem; though Pekka really deserves the credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this on a Windows or a Linux (or Mac) server? I believe the locale codes are slightly different on Windows... e.g. 'nl_NL' on Linux and 'nld_nld' on Windows.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28vs.71%29.aspx for Winows locale codes. They are different and not every locale is supported.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can try the command "locale" to know your locale.

```
$ locale

LANG=fr_CA.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="fr_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="fr_CA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_CA.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Then,

```
  setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_CA.UTF-8');
  ksort($my, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);
```